# Jakson JSON как использовать дженерики?

Tags: java, json, jackson, десериализация

Хочу сделать так, чтоб этот метод  «convertResponceInObjects» работал с разными объектами, но не получается

Идея подсвечивает эту «T[].class)));» часть кода, но как её заменить не знаю, гугление не помогает

Помогите пож-та заставить этот код работать

p.s. если убрать "T" и подставить объект, все работает норм

```
import by.bestproger.project.contextgoogle.yandex.entity.group.GroupData;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Util {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List <String> response = new ArrayList<>();
        response.add("{\"result\":{\"AdGroups\":[{\"Id\":3489546459,\"Name\":\"Optliner v1\",\"CampaignId\":37272735},{\"Id\":3813193305,\"Name\":\"Optliner v1 (копия)\",\"CampaignId\":43122041}]}}");
        List<GroupData> groupListTest = Util.convertResponceInObjects(response);
    }

    public static <T> List convertResponceInObjects(List<String> responceYandex) throws IOException {
        List<T> myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String el : responceYandex) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(el).get("result").get("AdGroups");
            try {
                List<T> temp = (Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(node.toString(), T[].class)));
                for (T elTemp : temp) {
                    myObjects.add(elTemp);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Метод convertResponceInObjects, ошибка (нужно положить в логи) " + e);
            }
        }
        return myObjects;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Само собой идея будет подсвечивать. Для этих целей есть специальный абстрактный класс com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference.

Используйте его вместо вашего

```
T[].class
```

вот так:

```
List<T> temp = (Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(node.toString(), new TypeReference<List<T>>() {})));
```